# Access user from Django form

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to access the user when a form submits. I have a timeline module which basically logs some events, and I'd like an event to be created from this form submit. And for that, I need the user.

What I have now is

```
def form_valid():
    timeline_msg = 'New session created at {0} on {1}.'.format(
        new_session.started.strftime('%H:%M%p'),
        new_session.started.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))

    new_session.create_timeline_events(self.request.user, timeline_msg)
```

However, I'm getting a ValueError saying that I'm expecting a User instance. When using pdb, I realise that `request.user` is returning a `SimpleLazyObject`. How can I get the User from this wrapper?

Comment: Can you  add your whole form and view code here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [request.user in Django Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357607/request-user-in-django-form)